# What's a sensible location for privacy or terms of service info for a page without a footer

Tags: placement, terms-of-service

For legal reasons, we now need to provide a link for privacy and terms of service information. This needs to be accessible from all pages in the system.

Normally this stuff goes at the bottom of the page in the footer. However, to maximize content real estate, our app doesn't have a footer.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcj5g7.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Content often contains large amount of tabular data requiring row totals etc. User would like things like total to be fixed at the bottom. So a footer isn't a good idea.

What's the next best location to place the link to TOC?

Comment: Is this a site? An app? What other sections do you have?

Comment: what's the existing layout of your app? fixed title bar? menu icons? is the content scrollable or fixed?  hard to answer without some idea of the constraints

Comment: time to introduce footer

Comment: @dnbrv This is a web app. Let me clarify the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see why you'd want to avoid creating a footer, given the complexity of the header (not a critique).

One threshold question is:  do the T&C's need to be *discoverable* or *visible*?

If **discoverable**, then I would place it under 'Help', because:

- Most of the header tabs are, appropriately, scoped for business flows.  The two tabs that are "out of flow" and deal with the app itself are: settings and help.
- Settings has a fairly specific meaning: user's expect to go there to adjust controls for the app.  Help has a more diffuse meaning, but generally users expect to go there to receive helpful information, so it's a more natural fit for T&C's.
- If a user wants to find T&C's and cannot see an obvious way to discover it, then they are likely to go to help anyway, so you have a redundant behavior that leads to the same place.
- T&C's often come with their own FAQ-style entries as the site grows ("how do you use my data?", "what third parties do you work with?", etc.) so placing them under the help rubric gives you ability to scale the content around T&C's.

If you need the T&C's to be **visible** from every page:

- I would first push back hard at lawyers who are asking for this, as it's typically only necessary in unusual cases (e.g. military, healthcare, trading, etc)
- If it's a hard requirement, then you may have no choice but to create a footer.

Comment: T&C needs to be readily accessible from every page. But we don't need to make the link visible. The 'help' on the menu already contains a drop down list with links to documentations, link to support forum etc. I wanted a sanity check because T&C's are a little bit different from Help. Thank you.

Comment: @nightning: Rename Help into Support. =)

Comment: @dnbrv Hah use both sides of term for Support. Nice! I actually lied a little in my mock. That top row there are icons instead of text. The help is a ?. Perhaps something like a life preserver? Hmmm although it's hard to say.

Comment: @nightning glad it was helpful. Perhaps consider using headings in the drop-down menu to denote separate portions (Common questions, Support, Terms & Conditions)....the use of headers is increasingly common

Answer (score 0):

In an app I would look for it behind an information button.

[image]

Comment: Should have better qualify that this is a large screen web app. Agree with you that for a mobile app the info button is a good place for this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in an app, it resides deep within the settings menu inside About page.
But if you are talking about website, you may include a legal link into your menu.

Answer (score 0):

You say it's an app in your comment? If so, include it as a link in the app's main navigation hierarchy (in android, for example, that would be a link in the [navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html))

Comment: Should have be more clear that this is a large screen browser type application. Navigation drawer would make a lot of sense on the android.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your wireframe, I would suggest the best location to be inside the HELP menu item.

Comment: That's my initial thought for where the link would go as well. But can you explain why?